# url rewrite not reading in php

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I am beginner in url rewriting and i have studied about it from various sources.Everything seems to be working till now but this is just not working.

I have this line of code in my htaccess file.

```
RewriteRule ^notice/all/page/([0-9]+)/?$ files/all_notice.php?show=all&page=$1 [NC,L]
```

This is the url i am visiting

```
http://localhost/notice/all/page/1
```

and when reading variables in php like this-

```
<?php
 $type=$_GET['show'];
 $page=$_GET['page'];
 echo $type.'--'.$page;
?>
```

This is what i get

```
all--notice
```

I am getting the show variable as it is but instead of page number i am getting notice.
What is going wrong?

Comment: what is the url you accessed?

Comment: @JanakaRRajapaksha http://localhost/notice/all/page/1

Comment: you catch the integer there, that mean the shown rule can not do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `RewriteRule` is this:

```
RewriteRule ^notice/all/page/([0-9]+)/?$ files/all_notice.php?show=all&page=$1 [NC,L]
```

Try this:

```
RewriteRule ^notice/all/page/([0-9]+)/?$ /files/all_notice.php?show=all&page=$1 [L]
```

The only difference is the addition of a `/` in front o `files/…` and removing the `NC` so it is only `[L]`.

**EDIT:** And perhaps you should see what happens if you change that `$1` to `$2`, `$3` or even `$4` to see if any of those values get passed through.

Comment: i am still getting "notice" instead of page number

Comment: can you suggest some other way of doing this

Comment: page=$4 will works since `([0-9]+)` is in the 4th place of `^notice/all/page/([0-9]+)/`

Comment: @JakeGould Sorry to bother, now I got your point why it is not listed.

Comment: @JakeGould Ah I thought you hate "not letting the devs to check" :)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
RewriteRule ^notice/all/page/([0-9]+)?$/ files/all_notice.php?show=all&page=$1 [NC,L] //for urls like localhost/notice/all/page/1/
RewriteRule ^notice/all/page/([0-9]+)?$ files/all_notice.php?show=all&page=$1 [NC,L] //for urls like localhost/notice/all/page/1
```

You have `?$` after the `/` but it should be after the regex class

Comment: shall I have the full path of all_notice.php file?

Comment: it is in root/files/all_notice.php

Comment: Is adding `^` or `/` before `files/...` fixed it?

Comment: I edited the answer
first rule for `localhost/notice/all/page/1/` and second for `localhost/notice/all/page/1`

Comment: The first rule is giving 404 and second rule is again giving "notice" instead of page number